# Bootstrap 3 @font-size-base larger on mobile

Tags: css, less, twitter-bootstrap-3, font-size

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and less. I like to have a @font-size-base that is larger on mobile devices. But since so many type values are derived from font-size-base, I would like to set this variable conditionally and I'm not sure how to that.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Currently I am doing something similar by using REM sizing. It does create some other issues though… http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine only one way to do that (without rewriting the whole Bootstrap thing), create a less file like:

```css
@import "boostrap.less";
@font-size-base: 20px;
```

And compile it as a separate css file (e.g. "bootstrap-mobile.css") to be conditionally included for mobile devices (instead of standard "bootstrap.css").

Comment: There's another way around: you could try same trick as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21181583 (for example by nesting "boostrap.less" into `.mobile` class with redefined `@font-size-base`), but AFAIR Boostrap generates a few classes that are incompatible with such "global nesting", see https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1709 for details).